# How to handle a situation in which i am receiving late paycheques

Tags: professionalism, human-resources

Note: Salary transfers are done through online transactions.

I switched to a new company two months back. I got my first salary by cheque delayed by 7-8 days because of some bank account issue. So, I ignored the delay.

This time again the same thing is happening. I have decided to tell the HR that i wont take the pay cheque and they should directly transfer the salary (which is the usual process).

Everyone else is receiving their deposits like normal - it's just me that this is happening to.

Is my approach correct? Am i being rude? Will this have a negative impact on HR(s) in spite of the fact that this mistake should not have happened and that too twice!

Comment: Is it written in your contract of employment that you will be paid by cheque each month?

Comment: No, its always transferred online directly into the accounts

Comment: HI Sachinist.  It's two weeks later ... **have you been paid**?  I truly hope so.  Please let us know.

Comment: @Fatster Yes..I have been paid :)

Answer (score 4):

As your employer is meant to pay you via a direct BACS transfer as per their terms in your contract of employment, this is reasonable ground to refuse to accept the cheque and request that they make payment via bank transfer.

If they genuinely have problems with their bank however, it may be not be possible for them to make payment via this method until the issues are resolved (and you can't get blood out of a stone) so you may not have any option other than to accept the cheque or wait for them to resolve the issues at the bank.

Providing you diplomatically explain your reasons for refusing the cheque due to failure to pay you on time, I would expect them to understand your grounds and it shouldn't cause any future uneasiness between yourself and the HR department. The bottom line is that it is the employer that is not adhering to their own terms of contract which places greater weight on your side.

Comment: *via a direct BACS transfer as per their terms in your contract of employment* - Actually the question says it is the companies standard policy.  There is nothing  in the question that indicates that there is a contractual obligation to disburse funds in this manner.

Comment: This is true @Chad although one would expect the companies salary payment terms to be included in the contract of employment hence my mention of this.

Comment: @zigojacko - I have been contracting for over 20 years and never had the explicit terms of how I would be paid defined.  It will say when and the currency but the how is usually at the discretion of company.  If it is define it is also included with the caveat "or other method of payment defined by the company"

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you received a full pay-check bodes well that you will receive another.  I've seen it take 3 months to get BACS setup.  The company that took 3 months was very large one, which was likely part of the hold-up.

If HR is in the same building, you might just request they hold your check and you can pick it up on pay-day.  HR is generally very willing to work with folks to make sure they are paid, as repeatedly paying late makes the company look unprofessional, and will loose them good employees.

Answer (score -13):

**Leave the company immediately, that hour.**  If you're reading this, do it before you finish this sentence.  Then, go speak to a solicitor or attorney about doing what you can to recover your money. It's that simple.

(It's extremely likely you'll recover nothing - after all they may be on the way to bankruptcy.  But that's life.  Re-read sentence two here!)

By the way.  "delays" due to "bank problems" are - quite simply - lies in 100.000% of such claimed events.

It's just silly, ridiculous, utterly nonsensical.

(It would be exactly, literally technically equivalent if I said to you: "oh, my email didn't reach you! because, uh, planetary email was, like - it wasn't working properly, man!"  it's just utterly, 100%, nonsensical.  A simple lie.)

---

## **Simple prediction:  Sach will get screwed and this will end with him losing money.**

The prediction couldn't be more straightforward and clear.

I'm happy to take one $10 bet (paypal!) with anyone who wants the other side.

(I won't actually take your money when I win, as it's a no-brainer.)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure this is a strategy that will see you gainfully employed for long. This isn't necessarily a fault with "the company": it could be a single person sat in the accounts office who hasn't learned how to run a new system properly. Speaking to a solicitor before you properly speak to your employer is a recipe for needlessly burning bridges. I'd suggest starting with open communication, rather than legal action: understand *why* it's happened and see if/how it can be resolved.

Comment: Quote: "This time again the same thing is happening"  The fact that four people have voted this down is sad, sad, sad.  The four people who marked this down -- will get screwed at some point! The OP is already screwed, and as sure as night follows day, he'll be back here in a couple weeks commenting "it's happened again, but I'm **talking** to them and giving them another chance.." and then in a couple months "oh yeah I got utterly screwed"

Comment: One of the four (i.e. me) has been paid late in the past by more than one company, has had a friendly conversation with the finance department in those companies, and then continued to be gainfully employed at those employees for many more payments without issue. Walking out of the door "immediately, that hour" without making an effort to resolve the problem is what would be "sad, sad, sad."

Comment: Worth noting that despite the lateness, the OP *has been paid*, but is choosing to refuse the payment. There's no suggestion that they've asked *why* the payment is late.

Comment: not even that, delays can happen due to many reasons. I've had late payments because of public holidays. Company sends out the orders to the bank on the same day each month, bank normally handles them the next day but that day is a friday and a holiday and they're closed. Weekend comes after that, so the payment only gets processed on monday at the earliest. Now they're 3-4 days late due to no fault of anyone really. Some companies have procedures in place to pay a few days early if such things look to happen in a month, most do not.

Comment: <ctd> or, being a small company, they have exactly 1 person who can handle the payments, and he's on a long weekend off the day he would normally do it, doing it instead on his return. Again, some companies would then have the payments handled early, others do it late. Depends on the company and their cash reserve situation at the end of the month.

Comment: `oh, my email didn't reach you! because, uh, planetary email was, like - it wasn't working properly, man!"` <-- You'd be surprised how often this sort of thing happens.

Comment: I'm also one of the four that downvoted and as an employer myself, in the very rare occassion, our payroll have actually paid a few employees late before, it was just a hiccup through no fault of our own but from direct experience can confirm, it most certainly does not categorically warrant the actions and points you're suggesting @Fatster.

Comment: @enderland I've actually once received an email with a 2 month delay, checked the headers and indeed it was sent 2 months before I got it (so it wasn't an attempt to mask a late reply by adding an earlier date to some text).

Comment: @jwenting that's my point, email delays do happen, which is just one more reason this is a ridiculous answer...

Comment: I do not think you have enough information to jump to this conclusion yet.